# How to edit a processing tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

Is it possible to make a copy of a tool from the Processing Toolbox in QGIS and make edits to it?

As an example, I would like to make a copy of the `Import geotagged photos` tool and then edit the code so that it also brings in extra fields from the EXIF data in the photo.

*Note: the goal of this question is figuring out how to edit a processing tool, not to bring in the EXIF data another way.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is - yes, it is possible. Although you would have to build QGIS from source all by yourself and bring in some C++ expertise because the algorithm you want to edit is only available as native C++ algorithm (see [`qgsalgorithmimportphotos.cpp`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmimportphotos.cpp) and [`qgsalgorithmsimportphotos.h`](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmimportphotos.h)).

Any enhancements to the algorithms are always helpful and appreciated!